# Nested State for Large Forms React

Tags: reactjs, performance, nested, state, setstate

When dealing with large form data, with regards to performance should that state be nested, or should you not nest state?  For instance consider if you had a form with 100 or more fields:

**Option 1**

```
state = {
    formData: {
        formItem1: value,
        formItem2: value
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
state = {
    formItem1: value,
    formItem2: value,
    formItem3: value
}
```

The second option above (not nesting) - would seem to pollute the state with a lot of fields.  The first option above (nesting) - I am not sure if this would cause performance issues on large forms when you update state.  For instance, to update state for option 1 above:

```
this.setState({
    formData: {
        ...this.state.formData,
        formItem1: newValue
    }
});
```

Because this is technically creating a new object for formData - would ALL form fields go through the re-render process since each one's state has been updated - and thus cause performance issues for huge forms?

Comment: You don't need to spread over the current state, but instead only need to specify what you want to change in setState. React will automatically merge the changed state with the rest. My suggestion would be: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" Just try it with whatever aproach you find better and when you run into issues you can optimize it later. Don't overthink it

Comment: To dismiss unwanted rendering, u can use the `shouldComponentUpdate` callback.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly modify nested state but you can do it as so you can use nested state as well and use your 1st option -

```
let temp = this.state.formData;
temp.formItem1 = newValue;
this.setState({formData:temp});
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to react official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) :

> setState() will always lead to a re-render unless shouldComponentUpdate() returns false. If mutable objects are being used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

I would recommend to store only those formItems in your state which are dependable to re-render the component. You can store all other formItems in variables and add them in your component state if necessary. This whole purpose is to avoid unnecessary re-renders.

- Sometimes the changed state is relevant for the rendering, but not under all circumstances. For example when some data is only conditionally visible.